# Spring Boot with Thymeleaf - null context

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My (very basic) jsp looks like this:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Comment proposal</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/common.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-primary text-center" th:text="${p.getTitle()}"></h1>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Content:</h2>
                        <h3 th:text="${p.getContent()}"></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Comments:</h3>
                        <div>
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr th:each="c : ${p.getComments()}">
                                    <td><div>
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <span class="text-muted" th:text="${c.getUser().getName()}"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <p th:text="${c.getContent()}"></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div></td>
                                    <td><a th:href="${'/upvoteComment/' + p.getId()}"
                                        class="btn btn-info" th:proID="${p.getId()}">Me Likey</a></td>
                                    <td><a th:href="${'/downvoteComment/' + p.getId()}"
                                        class="btn btn-info" th:proID="${p.getId()}">Nu-uh</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div th:with="idProposal=${p.getId()}">
                        <h3>Add comment</h3>
                        <form role="form" th:action="@{/createComment/} + ${idProposal}"
                            th:object="${createComment}" method="POST">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="contentInput"
                                th:field="*{content}" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                            <button value="Comment" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"
                                id="SubmitComment">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my controller serves this:

```
@RequestMapping("/commentProposal/{id}")
    //move to commentProposal.html
    public String commentProposal(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model){
        new ProposalDao();
        Proposal p = ProposalDao.GetProposalByID(Integer.parseInt(id));
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("commentProposal");
        model.addAttribute("p", p);
        mav.addObject("p", p);
        return "commentProposal";
    }
```

I've tried both returning the mav object, as well as adding the object to the passed Model. But to no avail, whenever I go on the page I get

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "p.getTitle()" (commentProposal:22)
```

And the maven window says "Attempted to call method getTitle() on null context object"

I've must've looked through countless tutorials, I just can't get what I'm doing wrong. Being a total noob in anything front end isn't helpful either!

Thanks!

Comment: It should be <h1 class="text-primary text-center" th:text="${p.title}"></h1>

Comment: Also, take a look at the Thymeleaf docs to represent your `href` links correctly.  And you can remove the `ModelAndView` lines altogether and just use `Model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dependency injection for Spring to find your DAO.  This can be simply done through autowiring (`@Inject` for Java):

```
@RequestMapping("/commentProposal/{id}")
public String commentProposal(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, 
                              Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("p", proposalDao.findOne(id));
   return "commentProposal";
}

@Autowired
private ProposalDao proposalDao;
```

Call it `findOne` instead.  This will make it easier for you later if you use Spring Data.  Also note that Spring can automatically convert types, so no need to parse your `Integer`.

Change your HTML template to match what you see in the Thymeleaf documentation:

```
<h1 class="text-primary text-center" th:text="${p.title}"></h1>
```

And change your method names to camel case (by convention and sanity for the next person reading your code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already sent the hand-in (thing is it was a group project, that's why the different types of casing, and I'm still trying to not use my C# mentality in Java, it's just harder than it looks).. The problem was actually in the DAO, under certain circumstances it would return null because of concurrency problems. Thank you, though!